Questions about Alfred Noyes' Midnight Express #4: Is Mortimer's death suicide or murder?
I have this(these) question(s) regarding Alfred Noyes' "Midnight Express"
Because I have about ten questions regarding this, I will post each individually.
I don't want to give any exerpt from the story because it is so intricately interconnected that it is best to give it a quick read. But still, here's a relevant excerpt:

The strange host was entering – moving toward him from behind – casting a grotesque shadow, larger than human, on the white walls in the guttering candlelight.
It was there, seated on the other side of the fire, facing him. With a horrible nonchalance, as a woman might prepare to remove a veil, it raised its hands to unwind the cerecloth from its face. He knew to whom it would belong. But would it dead or living?
There was no way out but one. As Mortimer plunged forward and seized the tormentor by the throat, his own throat was gripped with the same brutal force. The echoes of their strangled cry were indistinguishable; and when the last confused sounds died out together, the stillness of the room was so deep that you might have heard – the ticking of the old grandfather clock, and the long-drawn rhythmical ‘ah’ of the sea, on a distant coast, thirty-eight years ago.

So here's my fourth question in the series:

Is Mortimer's death murder or suicide?

Since Mortimer killed the "old man" and himself got killed (somehow), so that means he killed himself by killing him. So this raises the doubt whether sthe old man is his doppelganger or a harbinger of his future (his future self?)??
I think I shall include my fifth question along with this, which is relevant according to the excerpt.
Here it goes:

How are those sounds heard? (As in the last line of this passage)

This implies that Mortimer somehow went/teleported to his room in his Vatican style house again, but how's that possible?? Another interpretation that I got from an answer to my previous question is that is is a hint that the story repeats itself, but I'm not 100% satisfied with that logic. Did the room transform into his old house?

If you and your doppelgänger simultaneously strangle each other (assuming that this is what happened) is it suicide or murder?
